# How to drag and drop multiple items(selected using check boxes) using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I've tables like 
  Table1
    Column1
    Column2
    Column3
  Table2
    Column1
    Column2
    Column3
where there are check boxes in Columns, I want to check multiple columns and drag all the checked columns and drop it to other drag able area. The output will be suppose 
                Table2.Column1
                Table2.Column2
in the above case Column1 and Column2 are checked.

I am able to do for a single column only.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#tableOne").accordion();
            $("#tableOne li").draggable({helper:"clone"});
            $("#mergeDiv").droppable({drop:function (event, ui) {
                $("#items").append($("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.prop("class").split(" ")[0]+"."+ui.draggable.text()));
            }});

 });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <h2>Table</h2>
        <div id="tableOne">
            <h3>Table1</h3>
            <ul class = "source">
                <li class="table1">Col1</li>
                <li class="table1">Col2</li>
                <li class="table1">Col3</li>
            </ul>
            <h3>Table2</h3>
            <ul class = "source">
                <li class="table2"><input type = "checkbox">Col1</li>
                <li class="table2"><input type = "checkbox">Col2</li>
                <li class="table2"><input type = "checkbox">Col3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id= "mergeDiv">
            <h2>Dragable Area</h2>
            <ol id="items"></ol>
        </div>

</body>
```

I can only drag and drop one item at a time but it should be all the selected items

[image: Here 1. table2.Col1 2. table2.col2 should come]